# Gradle: Setting PMD Arguments minimumPriority and shortFilenames

Tags: ant, gradle, code-analysis, pmd

Is it possible to specifiy `minimumPriority` and/or `shortFilenames` with the Gradle PMD plugin? I want to migrate a build from Ant to Gradle, and I had an Ant task which specified these Attributes like this:

```
<target name="pmd">
    <pmd shortFilenames="true" rulesetfiles="pmd-ruleset-base.xml" minimumPriority="2"> 
        ... 
    </pmd>
</target>
```

I would like to use Gradles features and plugins instead of reusing this Ant task, but didn't find a setting in the [PmdExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension.html) for this. Is there any other way to specifiy these Attributes? Do I overlook something? I use Gradle 2.4. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Gradle 2.8, at least the `minimumPriority` can be set in the `pmdExtension`:

```
pmd {
    rulePriority = 3
}
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/2.8/release-notes#configuration-of-the-rule-priority-threshold-for-pmd